# I am using If/else condition on my code but i guess the the condition i am using for if/else is not proper

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, cypress

I am using If/else condition on my code but i guess the the condition i am using for if/else is not proper.Need help for getting proper condition that i can implement correctly in the cypress.io.

Explanation- i need a condition to implement,like-->when i will search any text(ex-july) on my filter searchbox then if that text is present, it should be visible but when the searched text(ex-july) is not present then it will display the text as "No data".
So for this i am trying to implement If/else statement.

If condition used below--> it will get element in which text is present, it should be visible, if that happens then verify whether text(july) is present
else--> will display the text as "No data"

Code written for if/else:-

Element for first row in which july(text) is displayed--> '.ant-table-row > .NameStyling'

```
namefilteredvalue(): this {

  if (cy.get('.ant-table-row > .NameStyling').should('be.visible')) {
    cy.contains("july")
  }

  else {
    cy.contains('No Data')
  }
  return this;
}
```

Problem facing:- only validating if statement if they will find text it will display the text but when not getting desired text not moving to else statement (which can show other text(no data))

using cypress.io.

Comment: Test should have the same expected condition every single time. Currently you are about to make test that will pass even if there will be no data returned. I suggest you write one test that checks if the `july` and the second that checks if for the non-existent data te `no data` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that if/else statements are not a good idea as Jonah pointed out, there are times you need them if the application under test is not consistent and may present the user with multiple options. Sometimes we are at the mercy of what the application DOES vs what is best test practices.

That said,

```
cypress commands return cypress promises
```

so when you type

```
cy.get('').should('be.visible')
```

it does not return true, it returns a chainable promise

likewise, with

```
if (cy.get('.ant-table-row > .NameStyling').should('be.visible'))
```

you are really typing

```
if(<cypress promise>)
```

which will always be true.